# CASE WHEN EXISTS not displaying values I know should be false

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I need help with THE CASE WHEN EXISTS, whenever it runs, it completes successfully, but CASE WHEN Exists statement doesn't display ongoing for a value I know does not equal 0. This query works on the few other tsql statements I've written, but not on this one for whatever reason. So values are returned, but showing up as completed, which is incorrect as one of the settings is in fact set to 1.

---

```
declare @STIG varchar(255)
SET @STIG = 'MS SQL Server 2016 Database'
declare @STIG1 varchar(255)
SET @STIG1 = 'MS SQL Server 2016 Instance'
DECLARE @VID2 varchar(20)
set @VID2 = 'V-71'


CREATE TABLE #temp2 ([DatabaseName] varchar(100), [DatabaseOwner] varchar(100), [is_trustworthy_on] varchar(5))

INSERT INTO [#temp2] (DatabaseName, DatabaseOwner, is_trustworthy_on)
SELECT name as DatabaseName,
SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) AS DatabaseOwner, is_trustworthy_on
FROM sys.databases

SELECT @@servername as [HostName], @VID2 as [V-ID], @STIG AS [STIG], (CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT is_trustworthy_on
    FROM #temp2
    WHERE #temp2.is_trustworthy_on = 0)
Then CAST('Completed' AS varchar(12))
ELSE CAST ('Ongoing' AS varchar(12)) 
END) as [Status]

drop table #temp2
```

---

The OUTPUT for the above should be,

SERVEREXAMPLE\Instance | V-71 | MS SQL Server... | Ongoing

Comment: Your case expression only checks whether there is *any* row in `#temp2` where `is_trustworthy_on = 0`. Since that temp contains all databases from `sys.databases` it includes`tempdb` and `master`, both of which have `is_trustworthy_on = 0`.

Comment: Maybe instead use `...WHERE #temp2.is_trustworthy_on = 1.....`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger correct, but the value for msdb is set to 1, so shouldn't it then return a value of 'Ongoing'?

Comment: Like I said, the CASE only checks whether there is any row that fits, and there is a row that fits. You are not selecting FROM anything, so you just get one row with the variables you declared and "do I have a database where is_trustworthy_on = 0"

Comment: there is no reason to have the case around the select statement with exists --- instead use it in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for `is_trustworthy_on = 1` if this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
  @@servername as [HostName], 
  @VID2 as [V-ID], 
  @STIG AS [STIG], 
  CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM #temp2 WHERE is_trustworthy_on = 1
    ) THEN 'Ongoing'
    ELSE 'Completed' 
  END as [Status]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT      @@servername as [HostName]
,           @VID2 as [V-ID]
,           @STIG AS [STIG]
,           DatabaseName
,           CASE 
                WHEN is_trustworthy_on = 0 
                    THEN 'Completed' 
                ELSE 'Ongoing' 
            END AS Status
FROM        #temp2
```

Comment: WORKS!, however I just need 1 row returned, which would be ongoing or complete. Preferably Ongoing first, and if all values =0 then only return 1 record with completed.

Comment: If you only want one row, for which database do you want to know whether it is completed or ongoing?

Comment: Well, you can't have both. You can have either one row, but only for one database; or multiple rows for all databases.

Comment: Well damn lol. Ok, thank's for your help! I'll think about putting it in another temp table and maybe i can work something out.